# Retrieve valid xml from socket

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'd like to read from a socket one byte at a time until a valid xml is returned. I can't seem to figure out the proper API provided by lxml as documentation isn't clear.

This is the scheleton of what I want.

```
from lxml import etree 
import SocketServer

class MyServer(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
  def handle(self):
    data = self.request.recv(1)
    for_,element in etree.iterparse(....)
       # check for completion and create entree object when completed
```

Is this the right way about this? Also can you guide me to etree APIs that make sense? I couldn't find if iterparse can take string objects